# Getting Error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save' on saving to Excel Sheet using Robot Framework

Tags: excel, python-2.7, robotframework

I'm trying to access the Excel sheet and write data into the sheet and save the result.
Below is the RF

```
ExcelLibrary.Open Excel /Users/tanyagrover/Desktop/StoreOpenandClose.xls                
ExcelLibrary.Put String To Cell Sheet1  2   0   10  
ExcelLibrary.Save Excel /Users/tanyagrover/Desktop/Storeopenandclose1.xls
```

But the RF code is giving error as :-
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save**
[image: RF Code Error]

Refer to the screenshot of the excel that my RF code is opening and writing data into.
[image: Excel Sheet]

Please can anyone suggest how to solve this error ?

Thank You

Comment: In my question above the Column is 2 and Row is 0, I've tried for Column as 1 and row as 0 with value 10-- strangely its working well for these but is creating another column with value 10 after Column with name as ID in my excel sheet

Comment: Report does not match with the given code. `Save Excel` vs `Save Excel Current Directory`. Please be consistent.

Comment: i've updated the screenshot with ```Save Excel``` it actually didn't work in both the cases - ```save excel``` and ```Save Excel Current Directory```

Comment: Which version of Python, Robot Framework and which ExcelLibrary are you using. Given that there are several around, the right one may be important.

Answer (score -1):

Try

`ExcelLibrary.Save Excel Current Directory    Storeopenandclose1.xls`

The keyword documentation in your report screenshot tells you to pass *only* the filename, not path.